# Getting (400) Bad Request in response while try get access token for docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am able get JWT access token with account id#10540382, which I created for our company e-signature implementation. I done JWT implementation with this account and everything goes well. But now company provided my new account id#11024495. But with this new account I am not getting access token. Token API https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token now return "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Can someone from DocuSign help me, what is issue with new account id#11024495?

Comment: Please let me know if any further more details require from my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is missing consent.
Your client will need to provide consent by calling this url from the browser window

`https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature+impersonation&client_id=integrator_key&redirect_uri=your_encoded_redirect_url`

Comment: Thank, I was busy some other work. I will update you.

Comment: this is not working. I got error message that "there are no redirect URIs registered with DocuSign ". I already sent email with snap shot. Please help me.